# C# unzip and read file from HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, http, zip

I'm trying to unzip and read file from `HttpWebResponse` object with followed code:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zae in za.Entries)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(zae.Open(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251), true, 2 << 18))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but getting `System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found`.
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Are you sure the response is returning a properly formatted zip?

Comment: @MikeFromCanmore i'm sure that file is correct, exception occured on line `using (ZipArchive za = ...)`

Comment: Can you save the file on disk and unzip it manually?

Comment: @tymtam of course, I checked this before disturbing the esteemed community

Comment: I'd try using System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is kind of what I was thinking with GZipStream (just an example, no guarantees here)...

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(response.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(gzipStream))
{
    Console.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```